# Why is Graphics adding all this whitespace above and below a simple Line[]?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to make a legend by hand. I know you can do it with various functions, but I'd like to do it by hand. All I really want is, I pass it a list of pairs of the form {label, legend properties}, and it will display a line segment with those properties next to the label. Here's my code:

```
labellist = {"a", "b", "c"};
dashingunit = .005;
thick = .005;
proplist = {Directive@{Dashing@dashingunit, Thickness[thick]}, 
   Directive@{Dashing@(3*dashingunit), Thickness[thick]}, 
   Directive@{Thickness[thick]}};
labelproplist = Transpose@{labellist, proplist};

llength = .8;
linelist = 
  Table[Row@{Graphics[{labelproplist[[i, 2]], 
       Line[{{0, 0}, {llength, 0}}]}, ImagePadding -> 0], 
     Style[labelproplist[[i, 1]], 18]}, {i, Length@labelproplist}];
Print@linelist;
Print@Column@linelist;
```

And it spits out:
[image]

I've selected the middle one to emphasize what I mean. For some reason, it's adding a ton of whitespace above and below each line, so when I form the `Column[]`, they're not that close to each other.

Adding `ImagePadding -> 0` to `Graphics[]` doesn't change anything.

Why is it adding this whitespace, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Easiest workaround would be to add `, AspectRatio -> 1/3` to your `Graphics` call.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/CkKjA.png

Comment: @JasonB thanks, maybe I'll try that. I want to know why the whitespace is there though. Does AspectRatio scale the image (as in, will it stretch the line and distort the dashing)?

Comment: I can't speak to how `Graphics` determines the `ImageDimensions` when they aren't supplied, and it will even change these based on whether you are viewing just the `Graphics` or part of a list.  So the safest thing to do is to supply your own `ImageSize` option (both x and y)

Comment: If you explicitly set the plot range in `Graphics`, e.g. `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}` you can get rid of the whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably caused by Mathematica trying to force a set aspect ratio on your graphics. Since a mathematical horizontal line has an aspect ratio of 0 my guess is that somewhere Mathematica divides by the aspect ratio (0) leading it into difficulties.

Compare the results for two lines that are virtually identical:

```
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0.0000001}, {1, 0}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Anything that will give the graphics object a non-zero vertical dimension will work, for instance adding an invisible point slightly off the x-axis:

```
Graphics[
  {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
   RGBColor[{0, 0, 0, 0}], Point[{0, 0.00000001}]
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A good combination of `ImageSize` and  `AspectRatio` will work as well:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> {400, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Awesome, this looks like it works!

Comment: It doesn't divide by zero, it's just avoiding degenerate graphics.

Comment: @BrettChampion You should know, of course, but I'd be tempted to say that a simple horizontal line shouldn't be that difficult to draw in a reasonable way.

Comment: `Graphics` doesn't allow degenerate values for `PlotRange` and will use {-1,1} if all the values are zero, or {0, 2v} if all the values are v.